# javascript could not work when refresh page

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jqm Ajax method to get data from servers , but when change to page2 from page1 and click Refresh , it won't be updated again . The only solution is to exit the browser and reopen it and go to the website again .Anyone can help me?

**Here is the code:**

Page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Page1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/wechat-mobile-custom.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.params.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url:"/gzdaxun/promotion/intf3_001action.action?newProductForJson=null",//get data from servers
                        dataType:"json",
                         beforeSend: function() {
                            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                             $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                        },
                        success:function(result){
                            var newProduct = result.newProduct;
                            $.each(newProduct, function(index, item){
                                var itemId = item.id;
                                $("#list1").append('<li><a href="page2.html?id='+itemId+'"><h1>'+item.name+'</h1></a></li>');
                            });
                                $("#list1").listview("refresh"); 
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("Error! Please try again!");
                        }
                    });
            });

            $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#page2",function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url:"/gzdaxun/promotion/intf3_001action.action?newProductForJson=null",
                        dataType:"json",
                         beforeSend: function() {
                            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                             $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                        },
                        success:function(result){
                            var newProduct = result.newProduct;
                            $.each(newProduct, function(index, item){
                                $("#list2").append('<li><a href="#"><h1>'+item.name+'</h1></a></li>');
                            });
                                $("#list2").listview("refresh"); 
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("Error! Please try again!");
                        }
                    });
            });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content" >
                <ul data-role="listview" id="list1"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Page2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page2</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="content" >
            <ul data-role="listview" id="list2"></ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1', function ()`. never use `.ready` with jQM.

Answer (score 1):

from the jQuery Mobile docs:

> **Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

so change your `$(document).ready()` to `$(document).bind('pageinit')` and it should work.